# subheader background color css is not showing up on HTML page

Tags: html, css, colors, background

So for some odd reason where it says "subheader" 3 times on the html page the background color which is blue isn't showing up. Why?

http://dgamerhelp.webs.com/soccer/Updates.htm

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you ever set it to blue? I'm using Firebug to look at your code, and you never seem to set the background color to blue in the sub. Add `background:blue;`

Look at websites like this: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/30-css-best-practices-for-beginners/

the best practices are to use classes instead of making your own tags. so instead of using `<sub>` use `<div class='subheader'>` and define that the same way you defined sub

Comment: See? sub {margin: 0;
    font: normal 5pt small fonts;
    background color: blue;
    text-align: left;
    color:  #ffffff;}

Comment: this is the sub that the page is actually using: `sub {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: 5pt small fonts;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}`

Comment: you might want to try reloading your css file. Also, what MightyPork says is true, although he should be nicer.

Answer (score -1):

1. Your page doesn't have a valid HTML syntax. You need doctype, html, head and body.
2. `<sub>` isn't a tag for subheader, but for subscript (like in H2O)
3. `<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="../soccer/settings.css">` Like seriously? WTF?

It should be like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../soccer/settings.css">
```

And I will rather not comment your stylesheet and using `<br>` to make paragraphs. It's beyond horror.

Comment: ahh i see yeah im bit of a noob when it comes to css

Comment: Doing that doesn't even change anything. What should I change sub to?

Comment: try correcting the missing space in that `<link>`, and your stylesheet will at last get linked.

Comment: And.. "`<color><blue>`"? You have CSS for this! Just wrap teh row into a paragraph tag `<p></p>` and style it with css.